# What is the remainder when 127127.........(a total of 202 digits) is divided by 143?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I am not getting any pattern to solve this problem please help?

Comment: But dividing by 1001 and by 143 is different thing??

Comment: Sumit Jha, what is $127\cdot 1001$? Answer, please. It is important for understanding Michael Rozenberg's good hint!

Comment: It is 127127 please explain in brief

Comment: Correct. So Michael's hint tells you that $127127$ is divisible by $143$. Therefore you can work miracles doing it six digits at a time.

Comment: has anyone noticed that 202 is not a multiple of 3?

Answer (score 1):

The hint: $1001=11\cdot13\cdot7=143\cdot7$